# Stripe InvalidDefinitionException when deserializing BankAccount object - Java

Tags: java, stripe-payments, deserialization, fasterxml

In short, I have a [Stripe bank account object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_bank_accounts/retrieve) that I am trying to return to the client/front-end.

```
HashMap<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
HashMap<String, Object> payload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
HashMap<String, Object> retrieveParams = new HashMap<>();

List<String> expandList = new ArrayList<>();

expandList.add("sources");
retrieveParams.put("expand", expandList);

customer = Customer.retrieve("cus_JHnmRG1q0aI3wt", retrieveParams, null);
         
BankAccount bankaccount = (BankAccount) customer.getSources().retrieve(customer.getMetadata().get("source"));
                 

payload.put("payment", bankaccount);   /*** Creates Error***/


response.put("payload", payload);         

return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
```

How can I send this bankaccount object back to the front-end, maybe a Hashmap or other JSON formatted object.

I keep getting the following error:

```
Type definition error: [simple type, class com.stripe.net.StripeResponse]; nested exception is
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class 
com.stripe.net.StripeResponse and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception,
disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["payload"]->
java.util.HashMap["payment"]->com.stripe.model.BankAccount["lastResponse"])]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by just appending `toJson()` as such:

`payload.put("payment", bankaccount.toJson());`

The downside to this is the additional `JSON.parse()` required on the front-end

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the ID instead, but it should be possible to get the JSON object from any Stripe Object ([source](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stripe/model/StripeObject.java#L55)), which you can then serialize/parse as you see fit.

Comment: Using the ID is not suffice, as it's a payment methods page that displays all payment methods currently setup on the account, so some additional information is displayed like last4, and bankname. There is an argument to just send those particular fields which I will instead of the complete object at some point. That being said I was able to work with it. - See answer.

Comment: Sure, that's fair if you want to eg display some portion of the account to be used in your UI. I still think it would be better to extract just the pieces you need rather than sending the entire objects.